# Помощь в алгоритме закраски фигуры

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-8

Суть задачи попиксельно нарисовать закрашенные фигуры(В данном случае круг)
Для отрисовки круга использую алгоритм Брезехейма.
Столкнулся с проблемой в самой заливке. Когда фигуру пересекает линия того же цвета, что и фигура. Фигура дальше не закрашивается.

```
private void fill(int x, int y, int r, int d, int v){
    if(pm.getRGB(x,y) != c.getRGB()){
        pd.drawPixel(x,y, c);
        fill(x + 1, y,r,d + 1, v);
        fill(x - 1, y,r,d -1,v);
        fill(x, y + 1,r,d,v + 1);
        fill(x, y - 1,r,d,v-1);
    }
}
```

`pm.getRGB(x,y)` - RGB текущего пикселя
`c.getRGB()` - RGB фигуры
Также я пытался поставить в условии, что если пиксель внутри фигуры то рисуй его, о там возникала проблема,что рисовались пиксели которые уже нарисованы и получался бесконечный цикл.

Буду рад если вы поможете мне с мои алгоритмом или расскажете о новом! [image: Прикладываю картинку с проблемой]

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы используете алгоритм Брезенхема, то на каждом шаге получаете координаты очередной точки `(cx + x, cy + y)` и нескольких симметричных, в частности, `(cx - x, cy + y)`.

Вот в этот момент и закрашивайте горизонтальную линию. между данными точками.